# How to search current word in elvis editor?

Tags: vim, elvis

How to search current word in elvis editor? just like * and # in vim.
In slackware vi is elvis.

Comment: That's a *control*-**A**

Comment: Ctrl-A works for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: If so, you can accept the answer which explains how to find the information: `ELVCTRL('A'):` is the program's symbol for control-A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably documented someplace, but reading the source code in `search.c`, you can see

```
      case ELVCTRL('A'):
      case ELVG('d'):
      case ELVG('D'):
            /* Free the previous regular expression, if any */
            if (searchre)
            {
                    safefree((void *)searchre);
            }

            /* Compile the regexp /\<\@\>/ */
            searchre = regcomp(toCHAR("\\<\\@\\>"), win->cursor);
            if (!searchre)
                    return RESULT_ERROR;
```

and in `regexp.c` the meaning of `\@` is explained as

```
#define M_ATCURSOR      265             /* internal code for \@ */

            else if (token == M_ATCURSOR)
            { 
                    tmpb = *cursor;
                    tmp = wordatcursor(&tmpb, ElvFalse);
```